# Is it possible to load a page from third party service into Salesforce login workflow

Tags: visualforce

I am new to Salesforce workflow. I would like to know following things on Salesforce integration;

Use case:

- User authentication happens on Salesforce website.
- once user is authenticated successfully, I wanted to make a REST API call to third party service.
- This third party service API calls returns/redirects to a html page.
- I wanted to load that page of a web service into the Salesforce page.

So would like to know
Is this possible to load a page from third party service into Salesforce login workflow?

I hope the use case is clear. Appreciate your help here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For handling/processing/controlling any thing, can be done through FLOW. You need to check login flows and from flow you can do callouts.

Showing a page, is a tricky part here. May be you can have a page which accepts URL as a param and you can show the same URL in Iframe.